# jquery adding element, need to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery that adds a textbox when the function is called.  Before I submit this textbox with the submit button I want to call a javascript function inside of the submit onclick to make sure that the textbox is not blank before submitting.  How can I do this I am not sure how to work with the element since it is added dynamically.

```
  $("<center><div><input type = \'submit\' onclick=\'\'  name = \'upload\' maxlength = 30/></div></center>").insertAfter("#"+innerid);

  $("<center><div><input type = \'text\' id = \'newteam\' name = \'newteam\' maxlength = 30/></div></center>").insertAfter("#"+innerid);
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', ':submit[name="upload"]', function(e) {
  if(!$.trim($(':input[name="newteam"]').val()).length) {
    alert('empty');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The form wrapping the textbox has an `onsubmit` property which takes a function. If this function returns false then the submit process is cancelled.

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp and http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I tried what you recommended and I got the alert for what I wanted and I put return false inside the function but it is still submitting.